# PSQLException: The server does not support SSL

Tags: pool, hikaricp

Environment

Windows
HikariCP version: 2.6.0
JDK version : 1.8.0_65
Database : PostgreSQL
Driver version : 42.0.0 org.postgresql

---

It works for some time, like 2 hours, then the exception raises.
My configuration:

```
    ds = new HikariDataSource();
    ds.setMaximumPoolSize(poolSize);
    ds.setLeakDetectionThreshold(15000);
    ds.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", serverAddress);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", database);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("user", user);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", port);
    ds.addDataSourceProperty("password", password);
```

My postgresql.conf is not set nothing related to ssl too.

Comment: Other people having the same issue on Windows: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/844 https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/788 https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/1905

Comment: It's me, I have opened these issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable SSL explicitly by setting useSSL=false

e.g.

```
ds.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");
```

Comment: It doesn't work, "ssl
Connect using SSL. The driver must have been compiled with SSL support. This property does not need a value associated with it. The mere presence of it specifies a SSL connection. However, for compatibility with future versions, the value "true" is preferred. For more information see Chapter 4, Using SSL."